# Submission error: please fill out all required fields

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to create a client on **Instagram developer console**, whenever I add ***Valid redirect URIs***: it gave me this error

**Enter a valid website.**

Here is the url I've added : *ig91d41531://authorize*

Thanks,

Comment: Pretty sure that needs to be a HTTP(S) URL, since that redirect stuff happens in the user’s browser.

Comment: but I've used this type of uri, in my previous app, as I've to integrate this in mobile application

Comment: If the error you are getting explicitly says that you need to input a _website_ address, then I doubt that the kind of URL you are trying to use is supposed to work here.

Comment: If I put a website url then this will not return callback to my mobile application

Comment: Well yeah, so much is obvious. But I can’t find anything in the instagram docs about whether they even have a login flow designed for native mobile apps ... Both methods mentioned here, https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/, happen in the user’s browser.

Answer (score 0):

Register new Client ID Error: "Submission error: please fill out all required fields."

I was also getting the same error. then solved.
How Does?
https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/register/

**First view:**
[image]

**Solution:**

**1-** Chrome extension install: Disable Content-Security-Policy
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden

**2-** verify reCAPTCHA

**3-** fix error.

**Last view:**
[image: **enter image description here**]